# Process Builder Page does not open

Tags: process-builder

When I click on Create -> Workflows & Approvals -> Process Builder, I am getting error page output.

I tried different browsers without success

The screenshot from Firefox

[image]

The screenshot from Chrome

[image]

Only for this sandbox I am having issues invoking the process builder whereas for prod it is working fine.

I searched online and folks have asked me to clear my DNS cache which I did but still I am getting issue while trying to open up process builder.

Has anyone seen this issue ?

Comment: Check your instance status from here as well
https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances

Comment: The instance status shows as green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is happening.

But this is how I fixed it

You have to use standard url without your custom domain like this.

https://cs5.salesforce.com/0Ab

This will take you to Lightning Components Page.

In there, set the flag on "Enable Debug Mode".

Once this is done, try opening your process builder

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add *.force.com as a trusted site to your browser prefs.